# Docker web server always returns status 200

Tags: php, docker, apache

I have problem with my web server hosted in `php:8.0-apache` docker container, always returning status code 200, even if it's set to different value. *Same code outside of container works correctly*

my `php.ini` file is:

```
log_errors=On
error_log=/dev/stderr
```

and php code is:

```
... some code ...

http_response_code(400);
exit;
```

but I receive response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Any ideas what's wrong with my setup?

edit:
docker file:

```
FROM php:8.0-apache

RUN echo "<?php echo '{some json content}'; http_response_code(400); exit; ?>" >> /var/www/html/index.php

COPY php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/
```

Comment: Can we see your dockerfile?

Comment: Are you sure that the `http_response_code(400);` is executed? Please share a minimum reproducible php code, so we can help to find out the root cause.

Comment: @AliTou docker file attached

Comment: @TruongHua yes, it's definitely executed

Comment: Have you checked for other errors? Which error reporting level did you configure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured what was the problem:

there was already sent header with status 200 when I called `echo "..."`, so `http_response_code(400)` was ignored.

To solve this issue (and reason why it was working with default configuration on my pc) is to set `output_buffering` in `php.ini` to some value, so output is not sent immediately.

```
log_errors=On
error_log=/dev/stderr
output_buffering=4096
```

see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8028987/1557025

Comment: Yeah, it's a solution but if you can move the logic to change response code to before the very first echo, you will be able to turn the output buffering off which will send the response to your client faster and reduce memory footprint in your server.